# code obfuscation for JAVA EE project

Tags: jakarta-ee, obfuscation, source-code-protection

Currently i have an JAVA EE Project using Spring and hibernate framework. We are deploying it to the tomcat server in WAR format.

Now the clients needs to obfuscate the code before deploying it to the server. I have googled and found that only Jar format can be obfuscated.

But now the scenario is we have not maintained the project into two different Projects like backend or something. If i split the project to A and B and the B can obfuscated and added into project A build Path. Is the only option we have ?

Please provide your valuable suggestions to obfuscate the project in a single without splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ant and Proguard they work fine packing and genarating your .war file.

Here two targets in Ant file whereas the first one you obfuscate your build and the second generates your war file.

```
    <target name="obsfucate" description="WAR Generator">
        <proguard configuration="<proguard-file>"/>
    </target>

    <target name="generate_war" depends="obsfucate"  description="WAR Generator">
        <war destfile = "<war-file>" webxml = "<path-to-web.xml>/web.xml">

            <fileset dir = "./WebContent">
                <include name = "**/*.*" />
            </fileset>

            <lib dir="<path-to-libs>/<lib>" />
            <classes dir = "<build-path>" />
        </war>        
    </target>
```